# How to set an accessibility identifier properly in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, appium, swiftui, xcuitest

I would like to be able to tap a concrete button on my stack of views. To achieve this, first I set on my code an accessibility id:

```
Button(action: {
                 withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1)) {
                    self.modalShown.toggle()
                 }

                }) {
                      FilterButton()
                     .accessibility(identifier: "modalFilterViewBtn")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
```

So, then on my text case I tried to look for that id:

```
IOSElement elem1 = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("modalFilterViewBtn");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem1));
    elem1.click();
```

And I obtain as a result: **An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.(..)**

Finally if I use the Appium inspector to know the accessibility id of my desired element, it seems to be another name that is not the same that I had set in code:

[image]

Even if I look for the element with that id("Filter"), it also can not be found during my test case.

So, what is the correct way to set this accessibility id using SwiftUI?

Thank you

Comment: Did you put button inside other button intentionally? What is the sense?

Comment: That button is directly inside into a VStack, Asperi. Thanks

Comment: Then what is `FilterButton`?

Comment: FilterButton is actually a HStack, the button view

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume it should be like

```
Button(action: {
    // action here
}) {
    // button label view here
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.accessibility(identifier: "modalFilterViewBtn")
```

Note in iOS 14+ there is [`.accessibilityIdentifier(_ identifier: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/accessibilityidentifier(_:)) instead. `accessibility(identifier: String)` [is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibility(identifier:)).

Comment: Yes! It has a lot of sense. I was setting the identifier in the button view instead of in the button. Thank you again Asperi